# Viewbox in Silverlight

Tags: windows, silverlight, viewbox

How can use "Viewbox" in Silverlight?

Comment: ViewBox is used when you want to scale content to fit within a container. For example if you had a huge image (i.e 3321x2575) you could put it in the ViewBox and it the container or the fixed viewbox width.

Answer (score 2):

Viewbox in Silverlight is part of the Silverlight Toolkit http://silverlight.codeplex.com and is not a core control. Besides this it behaves just like the WPF version and you can look at any WPF documentation to see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I found it while browsing.See if it is helpful or not.
[New layout controls in the Silverlight Toolkit](http://jonas.follesoe.no/NewLayoutControlsInTheSilverlightToolkit.aspx)